# inspect get_source() do not return full lambda code when passed to function as argument and lines break?

Tags: python, printing

Example is better than long speech:

```
import inspect


def foo(param1, lambda_ref):
    _ = param1
    print(str(inspect.getsource(lambda_ref)))


foo(param1=0,
    lambda_ref=lambda:
    1 +
    2)
```

output :

```
lambda_ref=lambda:
```

The wanted output would be :

```
foo(lambda_ref=lambda:
    1 +
    2)
```

Or just the lambda code itself, but if one get all lines at least its possible to just keep whats needed. It works if `param0` is not here.

Obviously in my case lambda code is much more longer so that its easier to read and understand if a line break is inserted just after the `lambda:` keyword. Is that a bug ? [`get_source()` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) is pretty vague about corner cases.

EDIT:
bug is still there if `getsourceslines()` is used instead of `getsource()`. the output is :

```
(['    lambda_ref=lambda:\n'], 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out by myself that the inspect package consider that "lambdas always end at the first NEWLINE" [line 957 of inspect.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/inspect.py). Cannot tell if its a python rule or over interpreted by inspect.